# Perl iterate over the number of regexp matches

Tags: regex, perl

I have some lines like

```
int foo[] = { a, b, c, d, e };
```

The exact numbers of elements in the array is unknown. I want to match it using `perl`'s regexp. I identify the lines using

```perl
if ( $line =~ /^\ *int\ *([a-z]+)\ *\[\]\ *=\ *{(\ *([a-z]+)\ *,?)+}\ *;/ )
{
  print $line;
}
```

**How can I get the number of matches, as I want to work on each of the elements in the array?**

Ideally, I would like something like

```perl
if ( $line =~ /^\ *int\ *([a-z]+)\ *\[\]\ *=\ *{(\ *([a-z]+)\ *,?)+}\ *;/ )
{
  my $count_of_matches = ??????
  for (my $matches=0 ; $matches<count_of_matches ; $matches++)
  {
    print $matches, "\n";
  }
}
```

which should result in something like

```
foo
a
b
c
d
e
```

I tried

```perl
my $count_of_matches = () = $line =~ /.../ # using the same pattern as above

my @list  = $line =~ /.../
my $other_count_of_matches = scalar @list
```

But I get a count of 3, and the `perl` array only contains the array name (`foo`) and twice the last element (`e`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First, match the whole contents of `{...}`, then use [split](http://p3rl.org/split) to retrieve the individual elements.

BTW, you don't have to backslash spaces (unless you use the `/x` modifier).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = 'int foo[] = { a, b, c, d, e };';

my ($array, $elements) = $string =~ /^ *int *([a-z]+) *\[\] *= *\{ *((?:[a-z]+ *,? *)+)\};/;
my @elements = split /[, ]+/, $elements;

say "<$_>" for $array, @elements;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you find regexes too limiting, use a real C parser.

```
use MarpaX::Languages::C::Scan qw();
my $ast = MarpaX::Languages::C::Scan->new(
    content => 'int foo[] = { a, b, c, d, e };'
)->ast;
for my $id (
    $ast->findnodes('//declarator//IDENTIFIER'),
    $ast->findnodes('//initializerList//IDENTIFIER')
) {
    say $id->getAttribute('text');
}
__END__
foo
a
b
c
d
e
```